# Linking two sql server from another server

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I have two servers, both have a sql server . Let's say srv1 has a sql-srv1 and srv2 with a sql-srv2 , i want to get some informations within sql-srv2 but making requests from sql-srv1.

my project is to create a script which could export data within sql-srv2 , in creating a bat files and to execute the script every day with task scheduler but first of all i have to connect the 2 sql-server and i don't know guys how to connect it, i'm a beginner.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need any of this. For starters, SQL Server's SSIS allows you to move data directly from one server to another. When you use the [Import and Export Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15) an SSIS package is created and executed. You can save that package and execute it periodically. If you want to create your own custom package you can use SSDT

Comment: If you want to take backups and restore them on another server, SQL Server offers real backups instead of dumps. Just [take a backup from one database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-a-full-database-backup-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and restore it on a new machine.

Comment: Honestly i don't know if that is possible bur sounds like an ETL, guess you can do that from powerbi guess

Comment: @Areu Yes that's it , i want to export a CSV file ! that's an ETL but i don't know where to begin

Comment: O great, yes you can use power bi or another bi to load that data from different sources and export in the format as you want

Comment: @Areu thank you , but i have to create a script like `sqlcmd -S . -d demo -E  -s";" -w 700 -Q "select * from etudiant" > C:\troisiemetest%date%.csv`   in a bat file to make it run everyday with task scheduler  (it's just an example of a request). Now i want to know if i can run a task planificiated with power Bi ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use external systems to connect both ways, or SSIS.

If you want do that directly from one server you can use the *linked server* feature in one or both of them.
From SSMS open Server Objects, Linked Servers and create a new one inserting the instance name and some credentials (maybe useful use the same credential).

Then you can inspect data using that syntax:

```
select * from [server].[database].[schema].[object];
```

Watch out some limitation if you fetch lot of data remotely (check *openquery* keyword) and more complex scenario involving distribuited transactions.

Check then the documentation to learn more about Linked Servers.